# Node.js / Mongoose - Adding, Updating and Deleting items from sub collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema in a node based web app, using mongoose.

```
var headerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    values: String,
    state: String
});

var responseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    responseText: String,
    active: String
});

var requestSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id: String,
    name: String,
    description: { type: String },
    url: String,
    verb: String,
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    headers: [headerSchema],
    body: String,
    responses: [responseSchema]
});
```

The request schema is the one that is stored as a collection within the mongo database, and the header schema and response schema are sub collections of it.

The problem I am facing is understanding how on an update to request schema document, what is the best approach for adding, updating and also deleting items from one of the subcollections, such as the responseSchema.

I am fairly new to mongo and have been have not been able to find a clear example of how this can best be achieved.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start off by assuming you've built a model of this using something like this:

```
var request = mongoose.model( 'request', requestSchema );
```

When you've got your model available Mongoose provides a few helper methods for dealing with sub-documents. First, note that you when you create a sub-document that Mongoose automatically assigns it a unique `_id` identifier. You'll need to know what this is in order to update or delete a given sub-document.

The quick example below outlines the main methods. This assumes that you know:

- `requestID` - the unique `_id` of the request
- `headerID` - the unique `_id` of the header sub document

---

```
request.findById( requestID, 
  function (err, request) {
    if(!err){

      // 1: Add a new header
      request.headers.push({
        name: "My header name"
      });

      // 2: Modify a specific header
      var thisHeader = request.headers.id(headerID);
      request.headers.nam = "My header name";

      // 3: Delete a specific header
      var thisHeader = request.headers.remove(headerID);

      request.save(function (err, request){
        if(!err){
          console.log('request saved: ' + request);
        }
      });
    }
  }
);
```